# JPA ManyToMany error when persistance

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I get an error when i use `ManyToMany` relationship to persist an object, I searched a lot about this problem but I can't find the solution, someone help me to find a solution for this problem please, here is my code :

**Utilisateur entity**

```
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String nom;
    private Integer theme;
    @JoinTable(name = "utilisateur_prvilege", schema = "sch_admin", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "privilege", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "utilisateur", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Privilege> privilegeList = new ArrayList<>();

..getters and setter..

}
```

**Privilege entity**

```
public class Privilege implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    private Integer pane;
    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privilegeList")
    private List<Utilisateur> utilisateurList = new ArrayList<>();
..getters and setter..

}
```

**Create new Utilisateur**

```
public void create(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(utilisateur);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a small change in the ManyToMany annotation. 
You are defining the ManyToMany mapping in Utilisateur but your join column(not inverse mapping) is `privilege` instead of `utilisateur`. Make these changes and it should work now.

```
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(length = 2147483647)
private String nom;
private Integer theme;
@JoinTable(name = "utilisateur_prvilege", schema = "sch_admin", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "utilisateur", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "privilege", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Privilege> privilegeList = new ArrayList<>();

..getters and setter..

}
```

add `em.flush();` line before commit and check

Many To Many mapping [Tutorial link](http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2012/12/17/jpa-2-relationships-many-to-many/).

Comment: Thank you @prem kumar, now the values is added in **privilege** table not in the assossiation **utilisateur_prvilege** , so how i can add the **id utilisateur and id privilege** in the assossiation table, this is my objectif?

Comment: you mean utilisateur_prvilege is not getting populated at all? but individual entities are getting persisted. can you enable show sql and see the sql statements generated

Comment: yes, the utilisateur_prvilege is empty and the values in privilege is duplicated, i really cant understand what happen!

Comment: did you check sql statements generated by enabling show sql ?

Comment: also do post how Utilisateur utilisateur is constructed while passing to create method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120317/discussion-between-youcef-laidani-and-prem-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

In

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privilegeList")
private List<Utilisateur> utilisateurList = new ArrayList<>();
```

add cascadettype property and give value to persist.

Comment: i set `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privilegeList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` i still get the same error, but the id in the error is incremented `Key (utilisateur)=(2) is not present in table "utilisateur"`, i do that before and i get the same error i really don't understand what is happen, what did you mean by **give value to persist** @Chetan Verma i don't understand it?.

Comment: I mean set cascade=CascadeType.Persist

Comment: from the error it seems like the issue  is from this code block  @JoinColumn(name = "utilisateur", referencedColumnName = "id") as it is saying this foreign key doesn't exist.

Comment: I edit my question and i add my tables, you can check relation of tables